# How can I increment this codes?

Tags: bash

I'm collecting data but some data I collected have like this output..

```
$ 2001 xei_1/2-10 
$ 2002 xei_2/3-7
```

It should be like this

```
$ 2001 xei_1/2
$ 2001 xei_1/3 
$ 2001 xei_1/4
$ 2001 xei_1/5
$ 2001 xei_1/6
$ 2001 xei_1/7
$ 2001 xei_1/8
$ 2001 xei_1/9
$ 2001 xei_1/10
```

Can you help me how I can increment this data using bash scripting? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: do you need to 'generate' the data like you're showing? or do you want to modify the data you're collecting? Your question is unclear I think

Comment: I want to modify the data I collected.

Comment: So far I have this code

Comment: requirement is not clear. why two `8`s? why `1,4` are missing?

Comment: while read var1 var2; do if [[ var1 =<var2 ]] then var1= `$var1 +1` ; echo $var1

Comment: I'm sorry the xei_1/8 should be xei_1/4 :)

Comment: It will be nice to clarify the question- feel free to edit it, so basically, you are just asking how to from this given strings separate only the part before ending `-<NNNNNN>`, where N means number, right?  I apologize, but its a slightly unclear, and I guess I am not only one..  ;) Btw you are askin "how to increment code", where is the code then? .. Kindly please follow [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be `awk` :

```
awk -F '[/-]' '{for(i=$2;i<=$3;++i) print $1"/"i }'
```

This splits each line in fields separated by `/` or `-`. So you have 3 fields, Field `$1` is what you want to keep. Field `$2` is the start of your range, and field `$3` the end. So a `for`-loop is all it takes and it prints the reconstructed version.

Comment: Yes, this is good. I used NF and split in case the slash or minus appears in the first field, but for simple inputs this is clearer.

Comment: @user000001 ah yes, this reasoning eluded me. It would be a good idea if you could add this to your solution.

Comment: It's a big help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

With awk you could do this transformation:

```
cat file
$ 2001 xei_1/2-10 
$ 2002 xei_2/3-7 

awk -F'[/-]' '{for (i=$(NF-1);i<=$NF;i++){a=$0;gsub(/\/.*/,"/"i,a);print a}}' file
$ 2001 xei_1/2
$ 2001 xei_1/3
$ 2001 xei_1/4
$ 2001 xei_1/5
$ 2001 xei_1/6
$ 2001 xei_1/7
$ 2001 xei_1/8
$ 2001 xei_1/9
$ 2001 xei_1/10
$ 2002 xei_2/3
$ 2002 xei_2/4
$ 2002 xei_2/5
$ 2002 xei_2/6
$ 2002 xei_2/7
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in {1..10}
do
  echo "2001 xei_1/$i"
done
```

Comment: Here OP wants a range `2-10`. The range seems correlated to the original file name (i.e. if the file is named `2002 xei_2/3-7`, the range will be from 3 to 7)